# VB.net- progress bar - see result when click step into but not run the program

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I find this to be very odd, I created a progress bar in my user form.

I put in my code section

```
Progressbar.value = 10 
Progressbar.value = 20
Progressbar.value = 30
```

Etc.

And then I click the step into of my code I see the progressbar being fill but when I run the code. I don't see it. Please advise.

Comment: In which method is that code? If that´s the real sequence you´ve posted than the progressbar value is (almost) instantly put to 30.

Comment: What I noticed after doing a couple test is that I put a break point after the progress bar run and click the run button and it doesn't display its movement. However when I run it till the end of sub it show updates. However if I do step into until after the progress bar without going to the end of sub I see it update.  This tells me the form doesn't update and I need a code to update it to see progress of the bar. Do you know a code that upgrades the bar, I tried to update the form doesn't work

Comment: You can call the `Refresh` method of a control to force it to repaint but the scenario you describe sounds extremely contrived and practically useless.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have a long code that is about 500 lines and I put the progressbar.value in each section to notify the users of how much the program has run. However I don't think this progress bar that I have set up is effective - it doesn't how in number or % how much has completed. I will try me.refresh every where I have progressbar.value to see if it updates. ;)